# How to filter keyboard input in windows

Tags: c, windows, keyboard, driver, kernel-module

I need to create windows driver, which will filter keyboard input to allow input only of numbers. I found [example of keyboard filter driver](https://gist.github.com/lnicola/2d8efb5412011678abb7), which disable backspace key, but I can't understand, what do the numbers 0x0E, 0x53, 0x80 and 0x1C mean in the following code:

```
VOID
KbFilter_ServiceCallback(
    IN PDEVICE_OBJECT  DeviceObject,
    IN PKEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA InputDataStart,
    IN PKEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA InputDataEnd,
    IN OUT PULONG InputDataConsumed
)
/*++

Routine Description:

    Called when there are keyboard packets to report to the Win32 subsystem.
    You can do anything you like to the packets.  For instance:

    o Drop a packet altogether
    o Mutate the contents of a packet
    o Insert packets into the stream

Arguments:

    DeviceObject - Context passed during the connect IOCTL

    InputDataStart - First packet to be reported

    InputDataEnd - One past the last packet to be reported.  Total number of
                   packets is equal to InputDataEnd - InputDataStart

    InputDataConsumed - Set to the total number of packets consumed by the RIT
                        (via the function pointer we replaced in the connect
                        IOCTL)

Return Value:

    Status is returned.

--*/
{
    PDEVICE_EXTENSION   devExt;
    WDFDEVICE   hDevice;
    PKEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA pData;

    hDevice = WdfWdmDeviceGetWdfDeviceHandle(DeviceObject);

    devExt = FilterGetData(hDevice);

    for (pData = InputDataStart; pData != InputDataEnd; pData++)
        if ((pData->MakeCode & ~0x80) == 0x0e && (pData->Flags & (KEY_E0 | KEY_E1)) == 0 ||
            (pData->MakeCode & ~0x80) == 0x53 && (pData->Flags & KEY_E0) != 0)
            pData->MakeCode = 0x1c | pData->MakeCode & 0x80;

    (*(PSERVICE_CALLBACK_ROUTINE)(ULONG_PTR)devExt->UpperConnectData.ClassService)(
        devExt->UpperConnectData.ClassDeviceObject,
        InputDataStart,
        InputDataEnd,
        InputDataConsumed);
}
```

I found [this file](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/translate.pdf), and according this, 0x0E is Backspace PS/2 Set 1 Make code. But what is other numbers mean?

Also, I need to get current state from API, and block input only when necessary. Can I dynamically load/unload this driver after system boot? Or I need to implement interaction between my API client and driver?

Comment: "but I can't understand, what do the numbers 0x0E, 0x53, 0x80 and 0x1C mean in the following code" --> Ah, the joy of naked magic numbers.

Comment: In your PS/2 table, `0x1C` is shown as 'Return'. Perhaps `0x53` is 'Delete' which isn't shown on the incomplete table. The `0x80` is possibly used for masking.